# Error while adding a Kotlin class in existing java/Android project

Tags: android, kotlin, android-glide

I am trying to use Kotlin within my existing android project. It uses many third party libraries like Android Annotations, Dagger, Glide etc. After making few necessary standard changes in build.gradle file I am getting this error.

> error: no suitable constructor found for
>   RequestManager(Glide,Lifecycle,RequestManagerTreeNode,Context)
>   constructor
>   RequestManager.RequestManager(Glide,Lifecycle,RequestManagerTreeNode)
>   is not applicable (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
>   constructor
>   RequestManager.RequestManager(Glide,Lifecycle,RequestManagerTreeNode,RequestTracker,ConnectivityMonitorFactory)
>   is not applicable (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)

This error is in the auto generated file GlideRequest.java. I am not getting any clue how to fix this. What possibly I could be missing here? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was making a silly mistake which caused this error. In case if any one else runs into similar issue, make sure that library and it's compiler(kapt/annotation processor) using the same version. e.g-

```
kapt "com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:$glideVersion"

compile com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:$glideVersion"
```

I had two different versions above by mistake.

Comment: Save my day! Thanks.